# Examining the convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+x}\text{ d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I'd like to have my solution verified for this one. I'd like to show that 
$$\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+x}\text{ d}x$$
is convergent. Notice, by partial fraction decomposition, that
$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+x} = \dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}\text{.}$$
An antiderivative of $\dfrac{1}{x^2+x}$ can be easily seen to be $\ln|x|-\ln|x+1| = \ln\left(\left|\dfrac{x}{x+1}\right|\right)$.

As $x \to \infty$, $\ln\left(\left|\dfrac{x}{x+1}\right|\right) \to \ln(1) = 0$ by continuity of $\ln$.

Thus 
$$\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+x}\text{ d}x = 0 - \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \ln\left[\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}\right] = \ln(2)\text{.}$$

Comment: It's fine, but if you only care about whether it converges or not it's quicker to simply note that $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+x}\text{ d}x\leq \int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}\text{ d}x$.

Comment: @GitGud - Ah, I was thinking that!... but I wasn't sure. Thank you!

Comment: how about $$\int_1^\infty \frac 1 x dx - \int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x+1} dx=\int_1^2 \frac 1 x dx +\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x+1} dx- \int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x+1} dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your solution is OK.** Observe that
$$
0<\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+x}\text{ d}x<\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}\text{ d}x=\left[ -\frac{1}{x}\right]_1^\infty=1.
$$